# Do gods appear on different lands

Tags: gods, tantra

Let's say I'm turiya, but I'm not in India, but some northern Europe country, and since I'm turiya, gods are supposed to come, since I'm turiya and they're pleased with my tapas, but will they still , because I'm not in India, or do they come to any place in the entire universe, or they're only programmed to appear to a location in India?
Also Will I lose my brahmanattva if I travel to location outside of India?

Comment: Experiencing God has nothing to do with geography.

Comment: You had stated that you are Turiya.  What's meant by Turiya?

Comment: Does not the sun rise in every places on the earth? And sun is the pratyaksha devata (the visible god)..